# Google Map Checking if cooridinate is between 2 points

Tags: android, google-maps, coordinates, google-polyline, google-directory-api

*ANDROID APP*

I've use google direction API to get a route from 2 points.

All the routes returned is saved if there is a need to reference to any of that data

Then I decoded the overview_polyline into a list of LatLng and drew the polyline on the google map.

How do I find out if a given coordinate (traffic accident for example) is on/nearby the polyline route , plus minus a constant distance (maybe 100m?)

Comment: what you want exactly .. distance between two point

Comment: I don't know how will that relate to finding if a point is on the route?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Google Maps Utility Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/?hl=en).

Especially `isLocationOnPath(LatLng point, java.util.List<LatLng> polyline, boolean geodesic, double tolerance)`.

Here's [the full documentation](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/).

Comment: Totally missed that out in the google maps utility library! Thanks a lot.